# Using Pig's ORDER BY on Return Value of Function

Tags: apache-pig

I am trying to sort using Pig on date string column `date_time_stamp`, however it looks like it cannot sort when a function operates on a column / field.

```
C = ORDER B BY ToDate(date_time_stamp, 'dd-MMM-yy hh.mm.ss.SSSSSS a') ASC;
```

Here's a sample data:

```
19-JUN-15 04.45.00.000000 PM,6
20-JUN-15 11.15.00.000000 AM,5
19-JUN-15 07.15.00.000000 AM,17
21-JUN-15 12.00.00.000000 AM,0
20-JUN-15 12.35.00.000000 PM,33
```

How do I sort on a column operated on by a function?

Comment: Share the test data for ref.

Comment: @MuraliRao I've posted it above. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per docs : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#order-by

1. The field_alias on which the ORDER BY is performed should be present in the relation/ alias.
2. Pig currently supports ordering on fields with simple types or by tuple designator (*). You cannot order on fields with complex types or by expressions.

In the use case shared, before performing an ORDER BY on alias B, we have to project the value of ToDate() as a field_alias and then we can perform an order by on this field.